# Working fine when hitting using Curl but Bad Request 400 when using python requests

Tags: python, curl, parameters, python-requests, bad-request

```
import requests
import json
import numpy as np

payload = {'query':json.dumps({
         "per_page":12,
         "sort":None,
         "scroll_id":None,
         "session_id":None,
         "q":"diapers",
         "shingle_active":False,
         "location":"110005",
         "types":["allopathy","brand","sku","udp"],
         "country":"",
         "is_query_suggestion_applicable":False,
         "debug":False,
         "filters":None,
         "source_fields":["count"],
         "query_filters":None,
         "is_all":True
       })}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url = 'https://kjhghfjdslsls' 
r = requests.post(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

This gives error :

> {"errors":[{"message":"Parameter per_page is required"}],"is_success":false,"status_code":400}

Though when using the below curl request it is working fine & returning required output-->

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://khjfhdksl' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '{
      "sort":null,
      "per_page":12,
      "scroll_id":null,
      "session_id":null,
      "q":"diapers",
      "shingle_active":false,
      "location":"110005",
      "types":["allopathy","brand","sku","udp"],
      "country":"",
      "is_query_suggestion_applicable":false,
      "debug":false,
      "filters":null,
      "source_fields":["count"],
      "query_filters":null,
      "is_all":true
    }'
```

Comment: Fyi you can actually use `json=payload` within your post which will reduce the need to create a JSON dump within `payload` -> https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: Thanks!! it is working

Answer (score 0):

You have a top-level key `query` in the payload for the python version. And you are passing the payload as `params` (query params)

Try removing that:

```
import requests
import json
import numpy as np

payload = json.dumps({
         "per_page":12,
         "sort":None,
         "scroll_id":None,
         "session_id":None,
         "q":"diapers",
         "shingle_active":False,
         "location":"110005",
         "types":["allopathy","brand","sku","udp"],
         "country":"",
         "is_query_suggestion_applicable":False,
         "debug":False,
         "filters":None,
         "facets":[{"field":"sku.brand.raw","name":"brand","type":"facet","range":None},{"field":"product_form","name":"product_form","type":"facet","range":None},{"field":"rx_required","name":"rx_required","type":"facet","range":None},{"field":"uses","name":"uses","type":"facet","range":None},{"field":"age","name":"age","type":"facet","range":None},{"field":"recommended","name":"recommended","type":"facet","range":None}],
         "source_fields":["count"],
         "query_filters":None,
         "is_all":True
       })
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url = 'https://search-stag123api.example.com/search-new/search/v1/search/lambda' 
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Cool. Feel free to accept the answer it it helped you out.

Comment: actually!! i got a solution from the 1st comment received. Has edited the same in your answer.Once it gets accepted, will accept it

Comment: The problem with using `json` is that it automatically changes your `Content-Type` to `application/json` - which may cause unintended side-effects